# Issue with using getters and setters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn about getters and setters. I'm actually having trouble understanding the idea.

I wrote this simple code, but it's not working.

```js
const person = {
  _age: 18,
  _drive: false,
    
  get drive() { 
    console.log(person._age)
    return this._age       
  },

  set drive(value) {
    console.log(value)
    this._drive = (value >= 21)
  }
}
    
console.log(person._drive)
```

I'm running the code using node. It's always returning false. How come?

But I think I didn't get the idea.

- GET for me is just to collect the value that I'm going to work with.
- SET is to set this value into somewhere.

Is that right?

Comment: That is `pessoa` ? Typo with the translation?

Comment: You're accessing the backing attribute directly, the accessors aren't involved at all.

Comment: You set the value of `_drive` to `false`, then output that value, which outputs `false`.  Can you indicate why you expected otherwise?

Comment: Read about getters and setters on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: I think you meant to call `drive` without the leading underscore (`_`). Also, it appears that you are calling `person._age`, instead of `this._age`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ECMAScript 2015 there are classes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
I believe you are looking for something like

```js
class Person {
  
   constructor(){
     this.age = 18;
     this.drive = false;
   }

   canDrive(){
     return this.drive;
   }

   setAge(age){
     this.age = age;
     this.drive = (age >= 21);
   }

}

const person = new Person();
console.log(person.canDrive());
person.setAge(21)
console.log(person.canDrive());
```

Demo: https://es6console.com/kd6b7cp0/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define a true `class` and provide an appropriate constructor?

When you get a "private" instance field, make sure you provide the `this.` scope.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(age, drive) {
    this._age = age
    this._drive = drive
  }

  get age()    { return this._age }
  set age(age) { this._age = age  }

  get drive()      { return this._drive  }
  set drive(drive) { this._drive = drive }
  
  toString() {
    return `Person[age=${this.age},drive=${this.drive}]`
  }
  
  get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    return 'Person'
  }
}

const person = new Person(18, true)

console.log(person)
console.log(person.toString())
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(person))
console.log(`age: ${person.age}`)
console.log(`drive: ${person.drive}`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want define getters and setters for simple object, you need to use Object.defineProperty()

Read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty